# How to get list of all email address who opened my mails sent through mandrill api

Tags: javascript, email, mandrill

Hi am sending emails to multiple email id's using mandrill API. Am getting the count for opens,unique_opens,clicks,unique_clicks,bounces and so on. what i want to capture is the email id's of the persons who opened and clicked my mails sent through mandrill API. and [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/users.JSON.html) is the link do get the count of the mails sent, opens and clicked.

Comment: have you tried anything yet ? Like any code

Comment: No i dint tried anything to get email id's..

Answer (score 0):

The [users/info](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/users.JSON.html#method=info) API you found provides account-level summary info, like you'd see on Mandrill's dashboard. I think there are two possible approaches to getting Mandrill click/open data for individual recipient addresses:

The first would be to use Mandrill's [exports/activity](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/exports.JSON.html#method=activity) API to generate a summary CSV, of essentially the same info you can see on the Mandrill [outbound activity dashboard](https://mandrillapp.com/activity): for each sent message, the recipient address, status, open count, click count, etc. -- exactly the info you're looking for, in one big file.

One downside is, exports/activity isn't synchronous. You call it, it *initiates a request* to generate the export, and then you have to keep polling to see if it's done. And then download the zipped CSV it's generated, unzip it, and parse the CSV. (So, you'll have to write a little code.)

The second approach is to use Mandrill's [messages/info](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=info) API to get the latest info for a specific message. The results include not only the open and click counts for that message, but *incredibly rich detail* about the opens and clicks: the user's IP, location and user agent, which URL they clicked, etc.:

```
{
    "_id": "abc123abc123abc123abc123",
    "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
    "clicks": 42,
    "clicks_detail": [
        {
            "ts": 1365190001,
            "url": "http://www.example.com",
            "ip": "55.55.55.55",
            "location": "Georgia, US",
            "ua": "Linux/Ubuntu/Chrome/Chrome 28.0.1500.53"
        },
        ... for each click
    ],
    "opens": 42,
    "opens_detail": [ ... similar to clicks_detail ... ],
    ...
}
```

The downside to messages/info is, you have to call it once for each sent message -- which means you also need to be keeping track of the `_id` Mandrill assigns the message when you send it (in the [messages/send](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send) response). (So again, you'll have to write a little code.)

With either approach, you'll need to experiment with *when* you run the queries. You'll want to wait long enough after a message is sent for most of the opens and clicks to have occurred. But, [Mandrill stores the detailed data](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583157-How-long-does-Mandrill-keep-data-about-my-emails-) for only 30 days (I think) -- so, you won't want to wait too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for more information like which URLs in the email were clicked, which browser etc. I would suggest using /messages/search.json which would return a maximum 3 months old data. search API  returns the same info as info api, but it spans multiple messages as specified by the query. It is more efficient that sending a info message for each email that you sent.

Also there is a limit of 1000 messages per search query. So you have to size your time window accordingly, in your search query ts:[START_TIME TO STOP_TIME]

Hope this helps,